# Python:How to calculate similarity score for two sentences based on WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

Are there any packages or methods for computing similarity scores for a pair of sentences based on **WordNet**?

I am doing some research about automatic summarization based on WordNet, and need to compute similarity scores between two sentences.

I was using **NLTK** and computing the score for every pair of words iterated over the two sentences, which take a LOT of time and inefficient.

I'm looking for projects/libraries/methods that already implement intelligently to compute similarity scores between two sentences based on WordNet.

In addition, I have found the similar question 
[Python:Semantic similarity score for String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022691/python-semantic-similarity-score-for-strings), but the package named **Gensim** doesn't look like what I want. So could you help me? Thank you!