# How to do semantic matching in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, semantic-matching

### Question:

I am trying to use semantic matching in Python on a group of words.

#### Sample Input:

```py
['error 1', '14_7error', 'err_87P', 'configuration 49-ñ', 'confi:p2g%']
```

#### Sample Output:

```py
['error 1,14_7error,err_87P', 'configuration 49-ñ','confi:p2g%']
```

### What I have tried:

I have tried using `sklearn`, but can get it to work, code:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = ['error 1', '14_7error', 'err_87P', 'configuration 49-ñ', 'confi:p2g%']

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)
pairwise_similarity = (tfidf * tfidf.T).toarray()
```

I have also looked at:

- [Python: Semantic similarity score for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022691/python-semantic-similarity-score-for-strings)
- [How to compute the similarity between two text documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/how-to-compute-the-similarity-between-two-text-documents)

But none of it has helped much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your input data, it seems that your goal is not semantic matching, but string matching. You can use [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) to do that:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process 
documents = ['error 1', '14_7error', 'err_87P', 'configuration 49-ñ', 'confi:p2g%']
results = [[i, process.extractOne(i, [x for x in documents if x != i])] for i in documents]
```

Results for best matches with matching score:
`[['error 1', ('14_7error', 71)], ['14_7error', ('error 1', 71)], ['err_87P', ('error 1', 43)], ['configuration 49-ñ', ('confi:p2g%', 60)], ['confi:p2g%', ('configuration 49-ñ', 60)]]`